# i want to sum 6 inputs and set the value to another input with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to sum 6 inputs and set the value to another input with javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/arispapapro/1qbjd36c/9

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="no301" class="form-control" id="no301" placeholder="">
  <input type="text" name="no301" class="form-control" id="no302" placeholder="">
  <input type="text" name="no301" class="form-control" id="no303" placeholder="">
  <input type="text" name="no301" class="form-control" id="no304" placeholder="">
  <input type="text" name="no301" class="form-control" id="no305" placeholder="">
  <input type="text" name="no301" class="form-control" id="no306" placeholder="">
  <input type="text" name="no307" class="form-control" id="thesum" placeholder="307">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var no301 = document.getElementById("no301").value;
var no302 = document.getElementById("no302").value;
var no303 = document.getElementById("no303").value;
var no304 = document.getElementById("no304").value;
var no305 = document.getElementById("no305").value;
var no306 = document.getElementById("no306").value;
var no307 = document.getElementById("no307").value;

var sum = no301 + no302 + no303 + no304 + no305 + no306;

sum.onchange = function() {
  thesum.value = sum;  
}

thesum.onchange = function() {
  sum.value = thesum;
}
```

Comment: where is script tag ?

Comment: What is your problem with this code?

Comment: check my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/arispapapro/1qbjd36c/9

Comment: should the sum update when a value is entered in an input?

Comment: yes it should update instantly.

Comment: sum.onchange and thesum.onchange  what are these trying to do. sum is just the sum of all values. I am not sure if you understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Please state the problem with the code in your question or it will likely be closed.

Comment: the value 'sum' doesn't emit an event so onchange never happens.

Comment: It is solved. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1qbjd36c/13/

```
$("form .form-control").not("#thesum").on("input", function() {
  var getSum = 0;
  $("form .form-control").not("#thesum").filter(function() { if($.isNumeric($(this).val())) return $(this).val();  }).each(function() {
  getSum+=parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
  $("#thesum").val(getSum);
});
```

1. `$("form .form-control")` A tag and class selector has been utilized to reference the target.
2. `not("#thesum")` added a not selector in order to avoid the change of input of Resulting TEXT field.
3. `on("input", function() {` utilized ON-INPUT event, to trigger all input formats, which includes paste of clip text too.
4. `.filter(function() {` utilized filter function to value only numeric values.
5. `getSum+=parseFloat($(this).val());`, here use of `+` indicates summing upon with the previous value to the variable, in other words, recursive change on value, which returns the sum of all iterated values.

Comment: *"check the fiddle"* isn't much of an explanation

Comment: ok, let me edit the answer with explanation, thanks @charlietfl

Comment: Welldone ameenulla007 thats the answer thank you so much.

Comment: you are always welcom, @arispapapro.. let me add some of the references to refer in future purpose, as a suggestion by charlietfi

Comment: could you give me the code for the specific inputs no301,no302,n0303,no304,no305,no306 only in your code you selle everything except sum, i want to to add only this inputs not everything?

Comment: better add a class to all the text fields you need to add up. and use a class selector there..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1qbjd36c/14/ check this out with reference to classes, and a better way to handle this out.. regards @arispapapro

Comment: you are always welcome.. :)